# Getting keyerror when trying to populate HTML via Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm making an HTML template that populates a table. The `show` in `value` refers to my model, `Show`, with values `title`, `network`, `release`, and `desc`. Here is the HTML:

--REVISED after suggestion from Abdul Aziz Barkat--

```
{% for show in object_list %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ show.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ show.title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ show.network }}</td>
                        <td>{{ show.release }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

My views.py:

```
def shows(request):
    object_list = Show.objects.all()
    context = {'object_list': object_list}
    return render(request, 'shows.html', context)
```

I can get the code to print in shell, as seen above. But when trying to populate my template, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 470, in parse
    compile_func = self.tags[command]
KeyError: 'show.id'
```

I'm not sure what base.py -> compile_func = self.tags[command] does. I'm assuming the problem comes from a miscommunication between my template and my views.py, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\django\django_fundamentals\semi_restful_tv\tv_shows_app\views.py", line 7, in shows      
    return render(request, 'shows.html', context)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render  
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 
34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 194, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 952, in do_if
    nodelist = parser.parse(('elif', 'else', 'endif'))
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 811, in do_for
    nodelist_loop = parser.parse(('empty', 'endfor',))
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 472, in parse
    self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 522, in invalid_block_tag
    raise self.error(
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 26: 'show.id', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in 
__call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line3 
6, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in 
__call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in 
__call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in techi 
cal_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in 
__call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in 
__call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in 
__call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in 
__call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 65, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 141, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\codingdojo\python_stack\my_environments\djangoPy3Env\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence
```

There is an important line in here that may help someone more knowledgable than me figure the problem out:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 26: 'show.id', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

But since I can get `show.id` to print in the Shell I don't understand why it's not registering in my template.

Comment: '{% for show in value %}' in each loop is show item is an object?

Comment: Why the brute forcing of all the variables in the session? `{% for show in request.session.object_list %}` obviously would work yet you decide to loop over everything in the session and try to access values over that... Also why do this? Why not simply pass the queryset into the context?

Comment: yes. request.session = {'object_list': Show.objects.all()} currently

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat I tried request.session.object_list and it had the same error as above. I'll try once more and let you know. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat I ran it and it came out like it did before, with the same error. I think I had changed it because I had gotten {% for key, value... %} to work in another program and wanted to try it in this one, then forgot it was the less elegant way

Comment: @ForrestGoryl I don't understand why you don't even get an error like `Queryset... is not JSON serializable` when you write `request.session['object_list'] = Show.objects.all()`, that should be giving you an error.

Comment: Is there a better way to add my objects into my template? Via context?

Comment: @ForrestGoryl do you have something like `{% show.id %}` somewhere in your template? Particularly line 26?

Comment: I have {% show.id %} in my template 8 times, but line 26 is a {% csrf_token %}. Maybe thats it! Will convert {% show.id%} to {{ show.id }}

It works! Can you make an answer so I can upvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session variable is not something that one uses simply because they want to render variables in the template. The session variable is used to store values for the current user until their session persists. This is particularly useful if for instance we want to store somewhat temporary values, some example usages are:

- If we allow the user to toggle between light and dark mode (CSS) on our website we may set their preferred mode in the session for ease.
- An e-commerce website wanting to store the anonymous users basket may set the **serialized** value of their basket in the session.

When one wants to render variables in the template one should be using the **context** for this purpose. The `render` shortcut function expects the context (dictionary) as it's third argument:

```
def shows(request):
    object_list = Show.objects.all()
    context = {'object_list': object_list}
    return render(request, 'shows.html', context)
```

Now in the template:

```
{% for show in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ show.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ show.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ show.network }}</td>
        <td>{{ show.release }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Also looking at your error you have something like `{% show.id %}` in your template, the syntax `{% something %}` is used for template tags. For referring to variables it should be `{{ show.id }}`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about session. I changed my views.py to match, but I am still returning the same error. I'll post the full traceback and the revised code.